# Getting Ã© instead of é when converting xlsx to csv with python

Tags: python, csv, utf-8, xlsx

I'm trying to convert xlsx to csv using multiples script in Python, they all work, but i'm getting Ã© instead of é in my files and i just don't know why. Here is one of the code i use :

```
`def Excel2CSV(ExcelFile, SheetName, CSVFile):
     import xlrd
     import csv
     workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(ExcelFile)
     worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(SheetName)
     csvfile = open(CSVFile, 'wb')
     wr = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

     for rownum in xrange(worksheet.nrows):
         wr.writerow(
             list(x.encode('utf-8') if type(x) == type(u'') else x
                  for x in worksheet.row_values(rownum)))

     csvfile.close()`
```

Comment: Aren't you checking with latin1 the output you explicitely encode in utf-8 ?

Comment: I'm just opening the file with excel

Comment: Use `f = open("myfile.txt", "wb", encoding="utf-8")

Comment: `TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function` i got this